# UILabel with adjustFontSizeToFitWidth enabled not hugging content height after adjustment

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have below a very simple example of a UILabel that will adjust the font size to fit the width.   However, when it shrinks the text, it does not hug the content height, as in the image provided.  Is this not possible when using adjustFontSizeToFitWidth?

Example code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let label = UILabel()
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.25
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 80.0)
    label.text = "A really long bit of text that will need to shrink"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0 ).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you want the text centered vertically? Or do you want it top-aligned? Or do you want to auto-size the height of the label, based on the auto-shrinking / scaling of the font?

Comment: your label's `minimumScaleFactor ` factor is 0.25, which is setting the font size to 20 as your label's given font size is 80. what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I want to use minumumScaleFactor, and I want the height of the label to hug the content.  @DonMag to answer your question, I want to auto-size the height of the label based on the auto-shrinking font, i.e. to hug to the content.

Comment: @KevinGray - ok, I think you'll have to jump through a few hoops to accomplish that. You can *vertically center* the text by setting `.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters`, however that won't "vertically hug" the adjusted font size.

Comment: @KevinGray As i got ur question, you just do number of lines as 0, for auto adjust height according to content.

Comment: @Mind_Sparkles that won't work here, because I want the number of lines to be 1.  If I do zero, it will do any number of lines

Comment: @KevinGray Otherwise u need to fix the height, or need to calculate the height of text according to font then update label height constant.